# how to add tabs to a SherlockFragment, not in a SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android

I am working in a project,that has tabs to the bottom of the page.
In one particular tab, I have to replace the existing `Fragment` with a `ShelockFragment`.
Now the fact is when I am trying to create the `actionbar` in my `sherlockfragment` code, I am not getting the `getSupportActionBar`(), which I get from a `SherlockFragmentActivity`.
how can I overcome the situation ?
I cant change my `SherlockFragment` to be a `SherlockFragmntActivity`. Because doing that wont let me replace my existing `fragment` to be replace by the `sherlockFragment`.

I have only one portion to use `sherlock` `actionbar`.

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have seen this example?

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-navigation-tabs-containing-listview-to-action-bar-in-pre-honeycomb-versions-using-sherlock-library/

Answer (score 0):

1) Parent layer (All Tabs are here) -EXTENDS SherlockFragmentActivity ; 
2) Its child (class[OR tab] where u want to use actionbar, i.e. CLASS holding actionbar )- EXTENDS SherlockFragment [HERE NEED NOT HOLD ACTIONBAR] ; 
3) Your actionbar -EXTENDS SherlockFragment ;

You need not to get getSupportActionBar() in ur (2nd class i.e. TAB class).
Just define it in Parent Class(1st pt.) and let it hold ur action bar there.
When required tab is taped just show those actionbars and in other cases HIDE these actionbar.